# Android Virtual Device Manager - Certain Targets not Available

Tags: java, android, eclipse, api, emulation

I am following a basic MyFirstApp tutorial for creating an Android App, but am having trouble getting the emulator to work. I am using Eclipse (on OS X) and was told to go to the Android Virtual Device Manager and select an AVD name, select Nexus 7 (2012) (7.0", 800 x 1280: tvdpi) as the Device name, and select Android 4.2.2 (API 17) as the device target. Problem is, even though 4.2.2 has been installed, it is not showing up on the list.

The only target option I currently have available is Android 4.4W - API Level 20. In addition to that, the CPU/ABI option is greyed out, saying "No system images installed for this project." The OK button is also greyed out. According to the SDK manager, though, everything necessary for 4.2.2 and 4.4W has been successfully installed.

I have Eclipse and Android Studio installed, and have used both (though not successfully when it comes to emulators). Could that have caused an issue?

I am new to this and would appreciate any help in getting the emulator working. I've tried everything I can think of and every search I can think of, so now I need someone to help me out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try either :

1. restart eclipse
2. install `ARM EABI v7a System Image` under the Android 4.2 section from the `SKD manager`

Comment: I managed to get my virtual device working. I restarted Eclipse like you suggested. In addition, even though ARM EABI v7a System image was installed for 4.2.2, they weren't installed for previous versions. Another Stack Overflow suggestion helped me with that. Now the emulator works, but my test app is not on the screen. (It was but I mistakenly clicked out of it and can't get it back.) So any advice for that would be greatly appreciated. But otherwise, thank you for helping me solve my initial problem.

Comment: @IanBryer  you can do that by two ways, 1- by running the app , eclipse will ask you if you want to add a AVD , click yes and that's it. 2- in the toolbar exactly under the `project` button there is a button called `Android Virtual Device Manager ` , click on it. both methods needs you to run the AVD or create a new one if you haven't create on before. if that helped please tick the answer to help others.

Comment: My apologies for taking a while to respond. Everything works now. (For now.) I appreciate the assistance!